# How can I get listOfValues or autoComplete in JSF

Tags: jsf

I want to use the listOfValues or autoComplete component in my application.
Currently I'm using tomahawk and not able to find any related component for autoComplete or listOfValues. Can anyone please suggest me if there is any other way to do it using tomahawk ?

Answer (score 2):

This requires a shot of Javascript/Ajax. Since Tomahawk is not an Ajaxical-flavored component library, you ain't going to find anything in there. You'll need to either write some (custom) Javascript (or better, [jQuery](http://jquery.com)) code around it or to go for a JSF component library with Ajaxical powers, like [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) which has a [`rich:suggestionBox`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/suggestionBox.jsf) for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

RichFaces has an easy-to-use version of `suggestionBox`, which is[`<rich:comboBox>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/comboBox.jsf?c=comboBox&tab=usage).

If you don' need the combo-part (i.e. the arrow for selection), you can either extend the component and get rid of the combo-part, or use `suggestionBox`.

I once decided on the 1st option, which turned out to be easier for my purposes.

Comment: +1 for suggestionBox and rich:comboBox, they work well and you don't have to write your own javascript ;o)

Comment: Thank you BalusC. I have implemented it using Javascript and it is working fine.

Comment: Thank you All (BalusC, Bozho, Jon) for the suggestions. I have implemented LOV using Javascript and it is working good. But I'm still not able to get the look and feel of the LOV pop-up is not as expected. Will try to make it look good, otherwise will like to go for either of the above suggested options.
Thank you again.